# Public types cant be declared in class modules

Tags: vba, class, ms-access, types

I want to create a function in a VBA (access) class module which returns a result type. Like this:

```
Public Type CheckResult
  isOk As Boolean
  errorText As String
End Type

Public Function Check() As CheckResult
    ...
end function
```

This function is used in a lot of different places.

But the compiler tells me, that it is not allowed to declare public types in class modules? Why is this? Where to put my Type instead? Should I create a new module just for this type? Or is it better to create a "AllTypes"-Module to put all Type-declarations in?

Answer (score 4):

As for the *Why* question:

Class modules are meant to be contained units of code: they do literally nothing if the class is not initialized.

Normal modules not so much. Any publicly declared thing in a normal module is available to everything.

It makes no sense to have a `Public` type in a class module, since if external code is using that type, it isn't accessing it through the class module. And if only the class module is using it, it doesn't need to be public.

It's sensible to organize your code in logical units. If it's logical to you to put all public types in one module, do that, but that's not a very scalable design decision. It's about as sensible as deciding to put all public functions in one module, and all public subs in another. For me, it's often more logical to put all error-handling code in one module, starting with all public type declarations used in functions in that module.

Comment: Can you help me understand how you do all of your error handling in a separate module?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I mean things like error logging and error displaying functions, debug levels, that sort of stuff. Of course, other functions call functions from that module. I used it here as an example because the type looks like one that's used for error handling.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is right.

So, as you have figured out, use a standard module for these declarations. I keep one module for such declarations (also enums) only.